# ZeroMQ and local FIFO

Tags: zeromq

I have two processes ('sender' and 'receiver') that need to communicate via a transient one way FIFO communication pipe, locally on a single machine.  Here's what I would like to happen (using language that's closer to Unix domain sockets):

- Sender "creates" pipe at well-known address, and immediately sends messages down it
- At some point (before or after sender "creates" pipe), receiver connects to pipe
- Reader reads messages off of pipe
- Sender "closes" pipe
- Reader notices that all messages have been read (possibly that pipe is closed)

My question is: how do I implement this with ZeroMQ?  "PUB/SUB", "PUSH/PULL"? What is the mechanism to detect the "end of data" in a ZMQ socket?  Is it possible to allow both of the orderings of the first two items above: That is whether sender or receiver attempts to connect first? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things to know about zeromq:

1. bind/connect order is generally not important
2. PUSH/PULL is used when one peer should receive each message and/or messages shouldn't be dropped
3. PUB/SUB is used when all peers should receive messages and/or messages sent when nobody is listening should be dropped.
4. ZeroMQ deliberately hides connect/disconnect open/close events from application code by design, so you cannot detect the actual close event.

An one thing you need to know for this, that you shouldn't have to: When a socket connects, it creates a pipe (the peer need not exist yet).  When a socket binds, it only creates pipes when peers connect.  These pipes govern the HWM behavior of the socket.  This means that the behavior for a connecting socket with no peer and a binding socket with no peer are different.  A binding socket with no peer will block if you try to send a message with it, while a connecting socket will happily queue messages in memory until the peer arrives and starts consuming messages.

Based on these points, what you want to do is:

1. use PUSH/PULL
2. *receiver* should bind
3. send a special 'close' message that indicates the queue is done, rather than detecting a tcp/ipc-level close event.

Here is a working example in Python that uses an IPC socket (a file) to communicate, where the receiver starts some time after the sender.

Common information both sides need to know:

```
import time

import zmq

# the file used for IPC communication
PIPE = '/tmp/fifo-pipe'

# command flags for our tiny message protocol
DONE = b'\x00'
MSG = b'\x01'
```

The receiver (PULL) binds, and consumes until DONE

```
def receiver():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    s = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
    s.bind("ipc://%s" % PIPE)
    while True:
        parts = s.recv_multipart()
        cmd = parts[0]
        if cmd == DONE:
            print "[R] received DONE"
            break
        msg = parts[1]
        # handle the message
        print "[R] %.1f consuming %s" % (time.time() - t0, msg)
    s.close()
    ctx.term()
    print "[R] done"
```

The sender (PUSH) connects, and sends, sending DONE to signal completion

```
def sender():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    s = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    s.connect("ipc://%s" % PIPE)

    for i in range(10):
        msg = b'msg %i' % i
        print "[S] %.1f sending %s" % (time.time() - t0, msg)
        s.send_multipart([MSG, msg])
        time.sleep(1)
    print "[S] sending DONE"
    s.send(DONE)
    s.close()
    ctx.term()
    print "[S] done"
```

And a demo script to run them together, with the sender starting first, and the receiver starting after the sender has already sent several messages:

```
from threading import Thread

# global t0, just for keeping times relative to start, rather than 1970
t0 = time.time()

# start the sender
s = Thread(target=sender)
s.start()

# start the receiver after a delay
time.sleep(5)
r = Thread(target=receiver)
r.start()

# wait for them both to finish
s.join()
r.join()
```

Which can be seen running together [here](https://gist.github.com/5069344).